# Why scala regex not match html a href

Tags: html, regex, scala

Here is my code

```
object RegexParser { 
  def main(args :Array[String]){ 
  val html = """test<a href="/web/content/">web content</a>""" 
  val Content = ".*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*".r
  html match { 
    case Content(c) => println(s"c=${c}") 
    case _ => println("wokao") 
  } 
 } 
}
```

why does html doesn't match the Content?

Comment: object RegexParser {
   def main(args :Array[String]){
     val html = """test<a href="/web/content/">web content</a>"""
     val Content = ".*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*".r

    //html need complete compare with Content
     html match {
       case Content(c) => println(s"c=${c}")
       case _ => println("wokao")
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Works on my machie. Which Scala version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like a charm (on Scala 2.9.2, so no `s""`).

```
scala> val html = """test<a href="/web/content/">web content</a>"""
html: java.lang.String = test<a href="/web/content/">web content</a>

scala> val Content = ".*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*".r
Content: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*<a href="(.*)">.*

scala> html match {
     | case Content(c) => println("c=" + c)
     | case _ => println("no match")
     | }
c=/web/content/
```